# Kotlin filter list within a list

Tags: kotlin

How can I return the original list (or a copy of the list) when trying to filter a nested list, I have the following method:

if I use .map I get the nested list as return, if I use a flatMap I get a nested list --> List>

```
private fun filterForShop(
        list: MutableList<WidgetItem>
    ): List<WidgetItem> {
        val result = list.map {
            it.compList.filter { comp ->
                comp.id != "square"
            }
        }
    }
```

My object looks like:

```
data class WidgetItem(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val kind: String,
    val compList: List<CompItem>
)
```

Comment: How does a `CompItem` look?

Comment: compItem => `data class CompItem(val id: String, val title: String)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `compList` is `val` we can only copy the old elements with the new `compList` value

```
private fun filterForShop(
    list: MutableList<WidgetItem>
): List<WidgetItem> = list.map {
    it.copy(compList = it.compList.filter { comp ->
        comp.id != "square"
    })
}
```

Comment: nice solution. I have one question if you could answer please.

what would be the solution if we want the predicate applied to CompItem -> title

data class CompItem(
    val title: String
) 

i am doing like this 

`code`
private fun filterForSearch(
    list: MutableList<WidgetItem>,
    filter: String
): List<WidgetItem> = list.map {

    it.compList.filter {
      it.contains(filter,true)
}.let {
it.copy(compList = it.compList.filter { comp ->
        comp.id != "square"
    })
}
}
`code`

in short i want to ignore the null list for WidgetItem including WidgetItem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.also()` to perform an operation but preserving the original context.

```
private fun filterForShop(
        list: MutableList<WidgetItem>
    ): List<WidgetItem> =
        list.also {
            it.compList = it.compList
                .filter { comp ->
                    comp.id != "square"
                }
        }
```

---

This would only work if `compList` is writable, which is not in this case.
You'll need to do it as @IR42 suggested.